# How to handle low-quality answers to low-quality questions

Tags: discussion, specific-question, low-quality-posts

For https://stackoverflow.com/q/34672077/1541563, I'm curious as to what the proper way to handle these *answers* is. Since they're all more or less link-only, is it sufficient to just close the question, or should any action be taken specifically on the answers as well?

Comment: I tend to downvote if the answers look like they were clearly posted in bad faith. (The only one that wasn't, arguably, is the guy pointing out the duplicate. He simply didn't have enough rep to vote to close it, and possibly no idea what the "flag" link means.)

Comment: When you feel overwhelmed with a question, just bring it to meta and watch natural selection take its course.

Comment: For future reference, if a poor answer is made to a poor question, the consensus is to just downvote the answer and omit flagging it?

Comment: Yes because flagging such an answer is a waste of time. You might as well just flag the question and hope that it goes down - which will take the answers with it.

Comment: Flagging Low Quality answers to already Low Quality questions is like double or triple dipping.

Answer (score 2):

In these cases I usually just downvote. Where applicable also flag the question as dupe/close for the usual reasons

Questions with no positive answers that are rated negatively and closed/marked as dupe are automatically deleted by the roomba after time, as far as I know.